# Gammu CMS Error 500: "unknown error"

Tags: linux, sms, gammu

Ao proceder ao envio de SMSes fazendo uso do [Gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/), para alguns números que estão ativos e a funcionar obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4 / 0
    [1] => Sending SMS 1/3....waiting for network answer..error 500, message reference=-1
    [2] => Unknown error.
)
```

Após múltiplos testes, não consegui encontrar um motivo para a falha, sabendo que a mesma acontece apenas em determinados números, noutros o envio ocorre sem problemas.

**Deteção**

Valores detetados fazendo uso do comando `gammu-detect`:

```
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port Vodafone__ZTE_ Vodafone_Mobile_Broadband_K3565-Z
connection = at

[gammu1]
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port Vodafone__ZTE_ Vodafone_Mobile_Broadband_K3565-Z
connection = at

[gammu2]
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
name = Phone on USB serial port Vodafone__ZTE_ Vodafone_Mobile_Broadband_K3565-Z
connection = at

[gammu3]
device = /dev/ttyUSB3
name = Phone on USB serial port Vodafone__ZTE_ Vodafone_Mobile_Broadband_K3565-Z
connection = at
```

**Configuração**

Este é o conteúdo do ficheiro de configuração em uso aquando do envio do SMS:

```
# VODAFONE
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyUSB1
model =
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = ./log/vodafone.log
logformat = textalldate
use_locking = yes
```

**Log**

```
[Gammu            - 1.31.0 built 03:39:58 Jan  3 2012 using GCC 4.6]
[Connection       - "at19200"]
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB1"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.2.0-34-generic (#53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012)]
Locking device
Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is down, CTS is down
Setting speed to 19200
[Module           - "auto"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 "ZTE INCORPORATED"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x22/34
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |5AZ|54T|45E|20 |49I|4EN AT+CGMI...ZTE IN
43C|4FO|52R|50P|4FO|52R|41A|54T|45E|44D|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK CORPORATED....OK
0D |0A                                                          ..              
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: ZTE INCORPORATED]
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x2F/47
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C, S: ("IRA","GSM",
22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      "UCS2")....OK.. 
Chosen GSM as normal charset
Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
Getting model
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D                                  AT+CGMM.        
1 "AT+CGMM"
2 "K3565-Z"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x19/25
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D |0D |0A |4BK|333|355|366|355|2D- AT+CGMM...K3565-
5AZ|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              Z....OK..       
Unknown model, but it should still work
[Model name: `K3565-Z']
[Model data: `']
[Model data: `unknown']
[Connected model  - "K3565-Z"]
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
[Module           - "A2D|iPAQ|at|M20|S25|MC35|TC35|C35i|S65|S300|5110|5130|5190|5210|6110|6130|6150|6190|6210|6250|6310|6310i|6510|7110|8210|8250|8290|8310|8390|8850|8855|8890|8910|9110|9210"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 "ZTE INCORPORATED"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x22/34
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |5AZ|54T|45E|20 |49I|4EN AT+CGMI...ZTE IN
43C|4FO|52R|50P|4FO|52R|41A|54T|45E|44D|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK CORPORATED....OK
0D |0A                                                          ..              
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: ZTE INCORPORATED]
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x2F/47
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C, S: ("IRA","GSM",
22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      "UCS2")....OK.. 
Chosen GSM as normal charset
Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
Setting date & time
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|311|344|2F/|311|322|2F/|311 AT+CCLK="14/12/1
300|2C,|311|333|3A:|344|333|3A:|322|311|2B+|300|300|22"|0D      0,13:43:21+00". 
1 "AT+CCLK="14/12/10,13:43:21+00""
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x25/37
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|311|344|2F/|311|322|2F/|311 AT+CCLK="14/12/1
300|2C,|311|333|3A:|344|333|3A:|322|311|2B+|300|300|22"|0D |0D  0,13:43:21+00"..
0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                              .OK..           
Getting firmware versions
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D                                  AT+CGMR.        
1 "AT+CGMR"
2 "BD_P673A2V1.0.0B09"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x24/36
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D |0D |0A |42B|44D|5F_|50P|366|377 AT+CGMR...BD_P67
333|41A|322|56V|311|2E.|300|2E.|300|42B|300|399|0D |0A |0D |0A  3A2V1.0.0B09....
4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Received firmware version: "BD_P673A2V1.0.0B09"
Number version is "67321,000900"
[Firmware version - "BD_P673A2V1.0.0B09"]
[Connected]
Setting to Unicode 119
Checking used: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 0, FreeText 67, UsedText 0, FreeBytes 134
Adding text
Copy 67 (max 159)
Text added
Checking at the end: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 134, FreeText 0, UsedText 67, FreeBytes 0
67 159
Checking used: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 0, FreeText 67, UsedText 0, FreeBytes 134
Adding text
Copy 67 (max 92)
Text added
Checking at the end: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 134, FreeText 0, UsedText 67, FreeBytes 0
134 159
Checking used: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 0, FreeText 67, UsedText 0, FreeBytes 134
Adding text
Copy 67 (max 25)
Text added
Checking at the end: UDH len 6, UsedBytes 50, FreeText 42, UsedText 25, FreeBytes 84
159 159
Entering GSM_GetSMSC
Getting SMSC
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCA?.       
1 "AT+CSCA?"
2 "+CSCA: "+351911616161",145"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x2D/45
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A AT+CSCA?...+CSCA
3A:|20 |22"|2B+|333|355|311|399|311|311|366|311|366|311|366|311 : "+351911616161
22"|2C,|311|344|355|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A              ",145....OK..   
SMSC info received
Parsing +CSCA: "+351911616161",145 with +CSCA: @p, @i
Grabbed string from reply: "+351911616161" (parsed 15 bytes)
Parsed phone string "+351911616161"
Phone string decoded as "+351911616161"
Parsed int 145
Leaving GSM_GetSMSC
Entering GSM_SendSMS
Trying SMS PDU mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|46F|3D=|300|0D                          AT+CMGF=0.      
1 "AT+CMGF=0"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|46F|3D=|300|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMGF=0...OK..
SMS Submit
Recipient number "XXXXXXXXX"
SMSC number "+351911616161"
SMS class -1
SMS validity ff
TPMR: 00 0
UDH, length 6

05 |00 |03 |91 |03 |01                                          ......          
Unicode SMS, length 67

00 |4FO|00 |45E|00 |54T|00 |20 |00 |4AJ|00 |61a|00 |6En|00 |74t .O.E.T. .J.a.n.t
00 |61a|00 |72r|00 |20 |00 |65e|00 |6En|00 |63c|00 |65e|00 |72r .a.r. .e.n.c.e.r
00 |72r|00 |61a|00 |6Dm|00 |65e|00 |6En|00 |74t|00 |6Fo|00 |20  .r.a.m.e.n.t.o. 
00 |43C|00 |6Fo|00 |69i|00 |6Dm|00 |62b|00 |72r|00 |61a|00 |2C, .C.o.i.m.b.r.a.,
00 |20 |00 |64d|00 |69i|00 |61a|00 |20 |00 |311|00 |322|00 |2C, . .d.i.a. .1.2.,
00 |20 |00 |322|00 |300|00 |2E.|00 |333|00 |300|00 |2C,|00 |20  . .2.0...3.0.,. 
00 |48H|00 |6Fo|00 |74t|00 |65e|00 |6Cl|00 |20 |00 |44D|00 |2E. .H.o.t.e.l. .D..
00 |20 |00 |49I|00 |6En|00 |EA |00 |73s|00 |2C,|00 |20 |00 |63c . .I.n...s.,. .c
00 |2F/|00 |70p|00 |72r                                         ./.p.r          
A mensagem a enviar é muita fixe!
Waiting for modem prompt
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|355|333|0D                  AT+CMGS=153.    
1 "AT+CMGS=153"
2 "> "
Checking line: > 
AT reply state: 7
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|355|333|0D |0D |0A |3E>|20  AT+CMGS=153...> 
Sending SMS
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x142/322
300|377|399|311|355|333|399|311|311|311|311|366|311|366|311|366 0791539111161616
355|311|300|300|300|399|388|311|311|399|355|377|377|300|366|377 5100098119577067
46F|311|300|300|300|388|46F|46F|388|43C|300|355|300|300|300|333 F10008FF8C050003
399|311|300|333|300|311|300|300|344|46F|300|300|344|355|300|300 910301004F004500
355|344|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|41A|300|300|366|311|300|300 540020004A006100
366|45E|300|300|377|344|300|300|366|311|300|300|377|322|300|300 6E00740061007200
322|300|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|45E|300|300|366|333|300|300 200065006E006300
366|355|300|300|377|322|300|300|377|322|300|300|366|311|300|300 6500720072006100
366|44D|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|45E|300|300|377|344|300|300 6D0065006E007400
366|46F|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|333|300|300|366|46F|300|300 6F00200043006F00
366|399|300|300|366|44D|300|300|366|322|300|300|377|322|300|300 69006D0062007200
366|311|300|300|322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|366|344|300|300 61002C0020006400
366|399|300|300|366|311|300|300|322|300|300|300|333|311|300|300 6900610020003100
333|322|300|300|322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|333|322|300|300 32002C0020003200
333|300|300|300|322|45E|300|300|333|333|300|300|333|300|300|300 30002E0033003000
322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|388|300|300|366|46F|300|300 2C00200048006F00
377|344|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300 740065006C002000
344|344|300|300|322|45E|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|399|300|300 44002E0020004900
366|45E|300|300|45E|41A|300|300|377|333|300|300|322|43C|300|300 6E00EA0073002C00
322|300|300|300|366|333|300|300|322|46F|300|300|377|300|300|300 200063002F007000
377|322                                                         72              
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x01/1
1A                                                              .               
Leaving GSM_SendSMS
1 "AT+CMGS=153"
2 "> 07915391111616165100098119577067F10008FF8C050003910301004F004500540020004A0061006E00740061007200200065006E00630065007200720061006D0065006E0074006F00200043006F0069006D006200720061002C0020006400690061002000310032002C002000320030002E00330030002C00200048006F00740065006C00200044002E00200049006E00EA0073002C00200063002F00700072"
3 "+CMS ERROR: 500"
Checking line: +CMS ERROR: 500
AT reply state: 5
RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x167/359
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|355|333|0D |0D |0A |3E>|20  AT+CMGS=153...> 
300|377|399|311|355|333|399|311|311|311|311|366|311|366|311|366 0791539111161616
355|311|300|300|300|399|388|311|311|399|355|377|377|300|366|377 5100098119577067
46F|311|300|300|300|388|46F|46F|388|43C|300|355|300|300|300|333 F10008FF8C050003
399|311|300|333|300|311|300|300|344|46F|300|300|344|355|300|300 910301004F004500
355|344|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|41A|300|300|366|311|300|300 540020004A006100
366|45E|300|300|377|344|300|300|366|311|300|300|377|322|300|300 6E00740061007200
322|300|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|45E|300|300|366|333|300|300 200065006E006300
366|355|300|300|377|322|300|300|377|322|300|300|366|311|300|300 6500720072006100
366|44D|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|45E|300|300|377|344|300|300 6D0065006E007400
366|46F|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|333|300|300|366|46F|300|300 6F00200043006F00
366|399|300|300|366|44D|300|300|366|322|300|300|377|322|300|300 69006D0062007200
366|311|300|300|322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|366|344|300|300 61002C0020006400
366|399|300|300|366|311|300|300|322|300|300|300|333|311|300|300 6900610020003100
333|322|300|300|322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|333|322|300|300 32002C0020003200
333|300|300|300|322|45E|300|300|333|333|300|300|333|300|300|300 30002E0033003000
322|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|388|300|300|366|46F|300|300 2C00200048006F00
377|344|300|300|366|355|300|300|366|43C|300|300|322|300|300|300 740065006C002000
344|344|300|300|322|45E|300|300|322|300|300|300|344|399|300|300 44002E0020004900
366|45E|300|300|45E|41A|300|300|377|333|300|300|322|43C|300|300 6E00EA0073002C00
322|300|300|300|366|333|300|300|322|46F|300|300|377|300|300|300 200063002F007000
377|322|0D |0A |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|53S|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R 72....+CMS ERROR
3A:|20 |355|300|300|0D |0A                                      : 500..         
Error 500
Sent SMS on device: "/dev/ttyUSB1"
CMS Error 500: "unknown error"
[Terminating]
[Closing]
```

Ao verificar o valor devolvido, já presente no output em cima, obtenho:

> Unknown error.

De acordo com a [documentação](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/index.html#return-values), é o erro 127, mas nada mais é facultado sobre como lidar com o mesmo.

## Pergunta

Como posso resolver este problema ou obter mais informações sobre a causa do erro `CMS Error 500: "unknown error"` de forma a entender o porque do envio falhar apenas em determinados números?

Comment: O comando que estou a usar: `echo "A minha mensagem" | gammu --config gammu_devices_cfg  text --sendsms TEXT XXXXXXXXX -autolen 4`. Adiciono mais tarde na pergunta quando surgirem novos elementos.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?